trying to write module for azurerm_storage_management_policy
I need to configure azurerm_storage_management_policy for module. I have wrote following terraform resource block and getting error during terraform plan. I believe this is something wrong with the variable .
main.tf
resource "azurerm_storage_management_policy" "mgmt_policy" {
  storage_account_id = var.storage_account_id

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.settings.rules

    content {
      name    = rule.value.name
      enabled = rule.value.enabled

      dynamic "filters" {
        for_each = try(rule.value.filters, {})

        content {
          prefix_match = try(filters.value.prefix_match, null)
          blob_types   = try(filters.value.blob_types, null)

          dynamic "match_blob_index_tag" {
            for_each = try(filters.match_blob_index_tag, {})

            content {
              name      = try(match_blob_index_tag.value.name, null)
              operation = try(match_blob_index_tag.value.operation, null)
              value     = try(match_blob_index_tag.value.value, null)
            }
          }
        }

      }
      actions {
        dynamic "base_blob" {
          for_each = try(rule.value.actions.base_blob, {})

          content {
            tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than        = try(base_blob.value.tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than, null)
            tier_to_cool_after_days_since_last_access_time_greater_than    = try(base_blob.value.tier_to_cool_after_days_since_last_access_time_greater_than, null)
            tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than     = try(base_blob.value.tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than, null)
            tier_to_archive_after_days_since_last_access_time_greater_than = try(base_blob.value.tier_to_archive_after_days_since_last_access_time_greater_than, null)
            delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than              = try(base_blob.value.delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than, null)
            delete_after_days_since_last_access_time_greater_than          = try(base_blob.value.delete_after_days_since_last_access_time_greater_than, null)
          }
        }

        dynamic "snapshot" {
          for_each = try(rule.value.actions.snapshot, {})

          content {
            change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = try(snapshot.value.change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation, null)
            change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation    = try(snapshot.value.change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation, null)
            delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than    = try(snapshot.value.delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than, null)
          }
        }

        dynamic "version" {
          for_each = try(rule.value.actions.version, {})

          content {
            change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = try(version.value.change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation, null)
            change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation    = try(version.value.change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation, null)
            delete_after_days_since_creation                 = try(version.value.delete_after_days_since_creation, null)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

**Variable.tf
**
variable "management_policy" {
  type = map(object({
    rule = object({
      name = string
      enabled = bool
      filters = optional(object({
        prefix_match = optional(list(string))
        blob_types = optional(list(string))
      }))
      match_blob_index_tags = optional(object({
        name = optional(string)
        value = optional(string)
        operation = optional(string)
      }))

      actions = optional(object({
        base_blob = optional(object({
          tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = optional(number)
          tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = optional(number)
          delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than   = optional(number)
        }))
        snapshot = optional(object({
          delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = optional(number)
        }))
        version = optional(object({
          change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = optional(number)
          change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation = optional(number)
          delete_after_days_since_creation = optional(number)
        }))
      }))
    })

  }))
}



**example.tf
**
management_policy = {
  rule = {
    name = "rule1"
    enabled = true
    filters = {
      prefix_match = ["test"]
      blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
    }
    match_blob_index_tags = {
      name      = "tag1"
      value     = "value1"
      operation = "All"
    }
    actions = {
      base_blob = {
        tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 30
        tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 60
        delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than   = 90
      }
      snapshot = {
        delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = 180
      }
      version = {
        change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = 30
        change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation = 60
        delete_after_days_since_creation = 90
      }
    }
  }
}

**Error - terraform Plan
**
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 125, in module "this":
│  125: management_policy = {
│  126:   rule = {
│  127:     name = "rule1"
│  128:     enabled = true
│  129:     filters = {
│  130:       prefix_match = ["test"]
│  131:       blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
│  132:     }
│  133:     match_blob_index_tags = {
│  134:       name      = "tag1"
│  135:       value     = "value1"
│  136:       operation = "All"
│  137:     }
│  138:     actions = {
│  139:       base_blob = {
│  140:         tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 30
│  141:         tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 60
│  142:         delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than   = 90
│  143:       }
│  144:       snapshot = {
│  145:         delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = 180
│  146:       }
│  147:       version = {
│  148:         change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = 30
│  149:         change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation = 60
│  150:         delete_after_days_since_creation = 90
│  151:       }
│  152:     }
│  153:   }
│  154: }
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for module.this.var.management_policy declared at ../../variables.management_policy.tf:1,1-29:
│ element "rule": attribute "rule" is required.




Creating storage management policy using terraform.

The main blocker is due to the way you define the variable file.
The variable file required rule to be defined which is missing the in your configuration.
I tried an updated configuration by making the management_policy variable is expceted to be a map with a rules key, where each rule is also a map.
Configuration:
main.tf
resource "azurerm_storage_management_policy" "mgmt_policy" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.management_policy["policy1"].rules

    content {
      name    = rule.value.name
      enabled = rule.value.enabled

      filters {
        prefix_match = try(rule.value.filters.prefix_match, null)
        blob_types   = try(rule.value.filters.blob_types, null)

        dynamic "match_blob_index_tag" {
          for_each = try(rule.value.filters.match_blob_index_tags, [])

          content {
            name      = try(match_blob_index_tag.value.name, null)
            operation = try(match_blob_index_tag.value.operation, null)
            value     = try(match_blob_index_tag.value.value, null)
          }
        }
      }

      actions {
        base_blob {
          tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than     = try(rule.value.actions.base_blob.tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than, null)
          tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than  = try(rule.value.actions.base_blob.tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than, null)
          delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than           = try(rule.value.actions.base_blob.delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than, null)
        }

        snapshot {
          delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = try(rule.value.actions.snapshot.delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than, null)
        }

        version {
          change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = try(rule.value.actions.version.change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation, null)
          change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation    = try(rule.value.actions.version.change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation, null)
          delete_after_days_since_creation                 = try(rule.value.actions.version.delete_after_days_since_creation, null)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

variable.tf:
variable "management_policy" {
  type = map(object({
    rules = map(object({
      name    = string
      enabled = bool
      filters = optional(object({
        prefix_match = optional(list(string))
        blob_types   = optional(list(string))
      }))
      match_blob_index_tags = optional(list(object({
        name      = optional(string)
        value     = optional(string)
        operation = optional(string)
      })))
      actions = optional(object({
        base_blob = optional(object({
          tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than     = optional(number)
          tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than  = optional(number)
          delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than           = optional(number)
        }))
        snapshot = optional(object({
          delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = optional(number)
        }))
        version = optional(object({
          change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = optional(number)
          change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation    = optional(number)
          delete_after_days_since_creation                 = optional(number)
        }))
      }))
    }))
  }))
}

variable "storage_account_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure Storage Account."
  type        = string
}

tfvars:
management_policy = {
  "policy1" = {
    rules = {
      "rule1" = {
        name    = "rule1"
        enabled = true
        filters = {
          prefix_match = ["test"]
          blob_types   = ["blockBlob"]
        }
        match_blob_index_tags = [{
          name      = "tag1"
          value     = "value1"
          operation = "All"
        }]
        actions = {
          base_blob = {
            tier_to_cool_after_days_since_modification_greater_than    = 30
            tier_to_archive_after_days_since_modification_greater_than = 60
            delete_after_days_since_modification_greater_than          = 90
          }
          snapshot = {
            delete_after_days_since_creation_greater_than = 180
          }
          version = {
            change_tier_to_archive_after_days_since_creation = 30
            change_tier_to_cool_after_days_since_creation    = 60
            delete_after_days_since_creation                 = 90
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

storage_account_name = "vinayccssstorageacct" 

Deployement:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks
azurerm_storage_management_policy | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry

Thanks a lot for the support. its work very well.

glad to hear it works for you @steve
